# Date Validation - Only enter dates within current month

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I've been assigned the task of validating a date field that gets populated when creating an invoice. It is a text box with three button objects that allow a user to select a date from a calendar, enter today's date, or remove the date entry.

My task is to make sure that users cannot enter a date that is NOT within the current month (double negative...tricky).
My task is to make sure that users can only enter dates within the current month. (better?)

I have no idea how to do this. Should I use the asp controls or do this on the back end?

I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: It is necessary to present a bit of code. Do you need client side validation (javascript) or server side (vb.net)?

Comment: Ivan, I'm so new I don't even know the answer to that question but I'd like to show some initiative? Which is better in general?

Comment: @IvanH - there should always be server-side validation, as client-side validation can be bypassed (i.e. JavaScript turned off), but the server must always validate everything no matter what.

Comment: @JettyJetty - the only "choice" should be if you also include client-side validation, server-side validation is a requirement!

Comment: Thank you. I will remember these tips from here on out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ASP.NET `Validator` controls, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox id="YourTextBox" runat="server" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="YourTextBox" 
    Text="The date field is required!" runat="server" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="compareValidatorDate" ControlToValidate="YourTextBox" 
    Type="Date" Operator="LessThan" ErrorMessage="Date must be from this month!"
    Display="Dynamic" runat="server" />
```

Note: I have included the `RequireFieldValidator` to ensure that we have a value to compare against for the date validation.

Code-behind (`Page_Load`):

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Dim firstOfTheMonthDate As DateTime = FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime.Now)
    Me.compareValidatorDate.ValueToCompare = firstOfTheMonthDate.ToString("d")
End If
```

Code-behind (utility function):

```
Public Function FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(dateTime As DateTime) As DateTime
    Return New DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1)
End Function
```

Note: I included a function to determine the date for the first day of the current month. The `Page_Load` is calling that function and then passing that to the validator as the value to compare for less than.

Comment: This is amazing thank you. I can take this and enter what is needed, but I'll still post the code I'm working with

Comment: @JettyJetty - great, glad it is useful to you. Feel free to up-vote my answer as well, when you are able to. :-)

Comment: I know right! I just a little more reputation and I got you sir

Comment: @JettyJetty - Getting close, two more rep needed. :-)